# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined | Node and node-mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-mysql

This has been puzzling me for a while, really have no idea what's happening. I'm fetching data from MySQL using the node-mysql module, when the results are ready I console log them and clearly see the results.

```
var sql = 'SELECT \
id, username, first_name, last_name \
FROM users\
WHERE username = ' + mysql.escape(req.params.username) + '';

pool.query(sql, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result[0]); //Object that contains all the fetched fields
  if ((result[0].username).toLowerCase() == (req.params.username).toLowerCase()) {
    console.log("We got a username!");
    profile.userData = result[0];
    profile.isAvailable = true;
    profile.theme = getProfileSexTheme(profile.userData.sex);
  } else {
    console.log("We dont have a username");
  }
  renderPage(profile);
});
```

Actual error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at Query.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/MyWebApp/routes/profile.js:24:23)
    at Query._callback (/var/www/vhosts/MyWebApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:134:8)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/var/www/vhosts/MyWebApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:78:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/var/www/vhosts/MyWebApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:143:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/var/www/vhosts/MyWebApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:127:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/vhosts/MyWebApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:202:24)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/vhosts/MyWebApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/vhosts/MyWebApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/MyWebApp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:72:28)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

(profile.js:24 is the line 
`if ((result[0].username).toLowerCase() == (req.params.username).toLowerCase()) {`)

From the console log, I get:

```
{ id: 24,
  username: 'Anna304',
  first_name: 'Anna',
  last_name: 'Pell' }
We got a username!

(These gets don't come from the console log but from node)
GET /profile/Anna304 77ms
GET /profile/style.css 80ms

undefined
```

How does that undefined get there? It doesn't appear if I comment `console.log(result[0])`, however this console log actually outputs the object containing the results of the query (just before the GETs we can see).

I also trying calling the query via AJAX after the page was loaded, and it worked (but I want to do it via the backend for the initial page load).

Any tips on how I could troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Saw this last night. Then, as now, I don't know where your error is showing up. Is it in the console output? Where does it appear in the output relative to other console output? More generally, your comment that commenting out your `console.log(result[0])` suppresses the undefined output makes me think for some reason it is getting called again. Change it to log just `result` to see what is there. Also you might find setting `debug:true` in your connection options helpful as it will give you full visibility to what queries are issued (although it is verbose).

Comment: Thanks, debug is really helpful. I see that the query is ran twice. It's ran a second time once the page is rendered, and calls the query with `WHERE username = \'{$value[\\\'thumbnail_url\\\']}\'' }`, (old PHP there is in the page than im migrating to node/ejs) then the console.log outputs `undefined`, then node crashes. I don't know why it runs twice, it seems as if the `app.get('/profile/:username'` I have in app.js is being called by something other than when I go to mySite.com/profile/Username

Comment: OK it works now. There were some hrefs in <<<TXT with PHP that were probably causing this, such as href="{$value['thumbnail']}", changing them all to href="" fixes the bug.

Comment: Can you show us the code to renderPage()?

Comment: The issue is fixed, it was in the .ejs file something was making the page render twice, with the second time passing a wrong value to the mysql query making node crash.